# Shell echoing every command

Tags: shell, shell-mode

(xpost from Unix Stack Exchange)

I'm using a local shell via an Emacs shell buffer. Seemingly at random, my shell will start echoing back every command I type before the rest of the output.

```
h ~ $ pwd
pwd
/Users/ericauld
h ~ $ echo $-
echo $-
himBCH
h ~ $ bash --version
bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.2.21(1)-release (aarch64-apple-darwin23.0.0)
h ~ $ trap
trap
```

Notice that neither `xtrace` (-x) or `verbose` (-v) are set.

Often I can get it to stop by restarting the shell.

```
h ~ $ pwd
pwd
/Users/ericauld
h ~ $ exit
exit
exit

Process shell<1> finished
h ~ $ pwd
/Users/ericauld
h ~ $
```

I notice there are two echoed `exit`s above, which could be a clue.

It seems to happen often, but not always, after I enter and exit a `pdb` session.

Comment: Do `stty -a` and check the `echo` part: in the case where the commands are echoed, that appears in the `stty -a` output as `echo`; in the case where they are not echoed, it appears as `-echo`. You can switch from one to the other with `stty echo` and `stty -echo`. Do `man stty` for (a lot of) details. I don't know why your shell starts with the `echo` setting on` *sometimes*.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```lisp
(setopt comint-process-echoes t)
```

> If non-nil, assume that the subprocess echoes any input.

(I'm not sure whether it helps because I can't reproduce what you described.  sorry)

Comment: This should probably be used when the command interpreter that's used by `comint` always echoes, but for a shell, I would turn off the echo with `stty -echo`. Some programs do the equivalent of `stty echo` and turn echo on and when they quit, they forget to turn it off so the setting is maintained, but Emacs cannot do very much about that.